# Can we deploy two mongodb services, using helm package in same cluster with different release name?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I used helm stable charts to install mongodb in my AWS kubernetes cluster, when i run helm install mongodb for the first time, no issues all pod runs and i am able to access the db too.

however, when i run helm install mongodb second time with new release name , pod logs shows that mongodb running successfully, how ever the status shows otherwise..

```
request-form-mongo-mongodb-7f8478854-t2g8z                        1/1       Running            0          3m
scheduled-task-mongo-mongodb-8689677f67-tzhr9                     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   4          2m
```

when i checked the describe pod logs for the error pod,

everything seems fine, but the last two lines are with this warning.

```
  Normal   Created                7m (x4 over 8m)   kubelet, ip-172-20-38-19.us-west-2.compute.internal  Created container
  Normal   Started                7m (x4 over 8m)   kubelet, ip-172-20-38-19.us-west-2.compute.internal  Started container
  Warning  FailedSync             7m (x6 over 8m)   kubelet, ip-172-20-38-19.us-west-2.compute.internal  Error syncing pod
  Warning  BackOff                2m (x26 over 8m)  kubelet, ip-172-20-38-19.us-west-2.compute.internal  Back-off restarting failed container
```

What could be the problem, and how to resolve this?

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about). **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
We can deploy multiple instances of mongodb on the same cluster using helm package.

The above issue is due to not allocating enough resource for my pv(persistant volume), issue got resolved when i dedicated min of 1Gi of memory for my pv and created respected pvc.

Once allocating enough resource i installed mongo db using helm successfully.

Comment: Is it possible to share same mongodb service via helm chart between two different apps.